# is it possible to connect yamaha psr s970 and Yamaha p115 digital piano?

Tags: midi, digital-piano

Is there any way to play my s970 sounds in Yamaha p115 by midi'ng them both? I feel that the s970 piano tones will sound good when it played in weighted keys. Is it possible to achieve that setup with these two keyboards? If so, what should I have to do? How do I connect them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The P115 does not have 'real' MIDI connectors; it has only a USB port.
And USB makes a strict distinction between a device and a host, so the P115's "USB TO HOST" port works only when connected to a host (a PC), not to another device.

The PSR S970 actually can act as a host, but its "USB TO DEVICE" port works only with flash drives.

To connect the P115 to the PSR S970, you have to put a PC/laptop in the middle.

(And most Yamaha USB MIDI devices are not class compliant, so the Kenton MIDI USB Host does not work either.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not by a direct connection.  There needs to be a computer running a DAW program in the middle.